# How to use PowerShell to remove space from the end of a line in a text file

Tags: powershell

I found a find-and-replace text answer from another question.

How do I use PowerShell to remove extra spaces at end of line in a text file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are a number of approaches but this one is pretty simple:

```
$content = Get-Content file.txt
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content file.txt
```

You may need to tweak the `Encoding` parameter on the Set-Content cmdlet to get the file output in the encoding you want (Unicode, ASCII, UTF8, etc).

Answer (score 0):

For small files (less than 250 MB) you could use:

```
$file = "Log20130820"

Get-Content $file  | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()}  | Set-Content "$file.txt"
```

For files that are too large, the script would fail with OutOfMemoryException.