# Removing extra spaces in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'd like to use PowerShell to remove superfluous spaces and replace them with a single comma between entries so I can convert the result to a working CSV file for further analysis.

Here is my code;

```
Get-Content –path C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\results.txt| ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "\s+"  " " } |  Out-File -filepath C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\results.csv
```

In the text file, the initial results are like this:

```
 entry     entry     entry    (all separated with 5 spaces)
```

What I want it to look like is this:

entry,entry,entry

So Excel will put them in separate cells.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you needed to replace with a `","` instead of `" "`. Let’s assume your text files lines are like the following. I don’t know if you meant the leading/trailing space to be there, but that's OK.

`" entry     entry     entry    "`

```
Get-Content –path C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\results.txt| ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace "\s+"  "," } |  Out-File -filepath C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\results.csv -Encoding ascii
```

`$_.Trim() -replace "\s+"  ","` use trim to remove outer spaces to prevent extra values in the CSV just in case.

Comment: Just a word of warning on Out-File. Default encoding is Unicode. `((Get-Content 'entry.txt') -replace ('\s{2,5}', ',')).Trim() | Out-File -Encoding ascii out.csv`

Comment: If you want ASCII encoding, you can trade Out-File for Set-Content, which  uses a default encoding of ASCII.

Comment: @kamikatze Good to know about the encoding. In this case I was just following what the OP had as far as output.

Comment: Also my oneliner is wrong. First Trim(), then -replace, otherwise the trailing spaces get comma'd. I did not account for that. How do i downvote myself ?:)

Comment: @kamikatze update your comment correctly and use backticks. Once it is ready just delete the incorrect comment. I already have that in my answer essentially anyway.

Comment: This is  what I was able to my question, Many thanks to all who contributed you were very helpful, this script gets me to 90% solution:

Get-Content –path C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Results.txt| ForEach-Object {$_.Trim( ) -replace "\s+","," } |  Out-File -filepath C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Results.csv

with the result is a csv file with all the answers commas included in the first cell of the spreadsheet, 
like this
5,48,469
any idea on how to get the numbers to break up into individual cells in excel??

Comment: @user177073 perhaps you need to set the encoding on outfile. See updated example. `Out-File -filepath C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\Results.csv -Encoding ascii`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trim` which *removes* characters (by default, spaces) from the beginning or end of a string. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579157/how-to-use-powershell-to-remove-space-from-end-of-line-in-text-file).

This can be done in another way if you want to do this with the replace character with a regex. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686816/removing-more-than-one-white-space-in-powershell) too.